# JSON sent over AJAX to Spring+Hibernate based application does not get persisted

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, hibernate

I am sending JSON object to a Spring+Hibernate+MySQL application.

Bellow is `index.html` where you can see the javascript making the request. Then there is `Customer.java` entity and `CustomerRestController.java` responsible for the request processing. Somehow my database is not getting updated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){           
         $('#btnBooking').click(function(){  
                 var custName=$('#userName').val();              
                 var custAddress=$('#address1').val();  
                 var JSONObject= {"name":custName, "address":custAddress};
                 //var jsonData = JSON.stringify( JSONObject );
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "http://192.168.1.12:8080/HomeServiceProvider/rest/customer/saveCustomer",            
                     data: JSON.stringify( JSONObject ),
                     dataType: "json",
                     processData: true,
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     success: function(data, status, jqXHR){
                        alert("success..."+data);
                     },
                     error: function(xhr){
                        alert("error"+xhr.responseText);
                     }
                });     
         });  
    }); 
</script>
</head>
    <body>          
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="scheduleLaterForm" name="scheduleLaterForm" action="#" method="post">
            <div class="col-lg-8">                                      
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Name:<font style="color: red;">*</font></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Full Name" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Address:<font style="color: red;">*</font></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <input class="form-control" name="address1" id="address1" placeholder="Full address" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group marg-bot-45">
                    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="btnBooking"> Confirm Booking </button>                                               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>              
        </form>                     
    </body>
</html>
```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -82689141527424144L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name="CUST_ID")
    private int custId;
    @Column (name="NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column (name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    public int getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }
    public void setCustId(int custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**CustomerRestController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerRestController {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CustomerRestController.class);

    @Value("${msg.customeradded}")
    private String message;
    @Value("${msg.successcode}")
    private int code;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Status saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer){
        try {
            customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
            return new Status(code, message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Status(0, e.toString());
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllCustomer",method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Customer> getAllCustomer(){
        List<Customer> customers = null;
        try {
            customers = customerService.getAllCustomer();
        log.info("Size:"+customers.size());
        log.info("customers:"+customers);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

**CustomerService.java**

```
public interface CustomerService {

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer);
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomer();

}
```

**CustomerServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CustomerServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    public void saveCustomer(Customer customer) {
        log.info("customer first name:" + customer.getCustName());
        customerDao.saveCustomer(customer);
    }
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomer() {
        List<Customer> customers = customerDao.getAllCustomer();
        log.info("Size:"+customers.size());
        log.info("customers:"+customers);
        return customers;
    }
}


Name of My table is CUSTOMER and columns are
```

colomn1: CUST_ID
colomn2: NAME
colomn3: ADDRESS

Comment: Is the method saveCustomer() of your service defined with a @Transactional annotation ?

Comment: You need to tell us more what is happening. Is your service being called? Do you get error back from the controller?

Comment: @PavelHoral i though posting json was an issue, and OP is using SPring, so i gave what i did.

Comment: @Fouad HAMDI, as you asked Is the method saveCustomer() : yes please check in this link http://ideone.com/Arpf9O

Comment: @Pavel Horal, Is your service being called? : Yes   Do you get error back from the controller?=> No

Comment: @ankur-singhal, Please tell my what was the issue and where you changed

Comment: @neelabhsingh i did not understood your problem completely, what i thought was you have some object populated in java class, and you need to call a restfull service and post a json data using SPring.

Comment: @ankur-singhal, Thanks for your reply,  I made form with customer name and address now I am sending this data as Json object. I have table Name customer where I have to populate the customer Data But I am not getting success,

Comment: In your question, you should provide the code of your CustomerService interface and of your CustomerServiceImpl class.

Comment: @Fouad HAMDI, please check I updated according to you

Comment: Add a @Transactional annotation above your saveCustomer() method in your CustomerServiceImpl class. Without it, your data will not be persisted in the database.